# How to avoid cascading ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, ngoninit

I have two component with parent and child relationship. Parent component's ngOnInit method checks if the user is logged in or not, if it's not logged in it navigates to the login page.

```
class ParentComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(){
        if(!authService.loggedIn){ 
           //navigate to login screen code
           return;
        }
    }
}

class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(){
        /** POINT TO BE NOTED **/
        // this function is also called even if ngOnInit 
        // of parent navigates to different component and returns.
        // do some stuff with userService.token
        // but because token isn't available the calls fail
    }
}
```

How do I block this cascading OnInit calls if parent component wants to navigate to other component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, you should not check if the user is logged in and navigate away from a component. You should instead use a [guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard) to do that.

But, to answer your question, you could just use

```
<child *ngIf="isLoggedIn()"></child>
```

That would prevent the child component to be created if the user is not logged in.

Comment: I knew the URL guarding, but I thought just returning from the parent's ngOnInit will work, but it doesn't work that way.

URL Guarding is surely the right way to do it, it happens during the navigation before the component is initialised. Thanks a lot, man.